# True/False - Are these sets and sequences open sets or closed sets?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Question**: Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and  $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ are sequences in $X$. $\{x_n\}$ has no convergent sub-sequence in $X$ and $\{y_n\}$ has only one convergent subsequence in $X$:- $\{y_{m_n}\}$ . Let $S$ be a subset of $X$.

**Then,which of the following is true:**

$1$.  If $z \in S$ is an isolated point of $S$, then it is possible that $z$ may be a boundary point of $S$.

$2.$ Every subset $H$ of $\{x_n\}$ consists entirely of isolated points of $H$ and is hence **open** in $X$.

$3.$ Every subset $H$ of $\{x_n\}$ consists entirely of isolated points of $H$ and is hence **closed** in $X$.

$4.$ The set $\{y_{m_n}\}$ is closed in $\{y_n\}$.

$5.$ The set $\{y_n\} - \{y_{m_n}\}$ is open in $X$.

**Attempt:**

$1.$ **True**. An isolated point in $S$ may be at $0$ distance from $S^c$. Example: the set of Natural numbers in Real Numbers.

$2.$ **False.** Every subset $H$ of $\{x_n\}$ consists entirely of isolated points of $H$ and each isolated point $i$ is open in $H$ and so is their union. . But, $\bigcup i$ may not be isolated in $X$ and hence may not be open. ( As then, the set itself becomes a part of the boundary of the set).

$3.$ **True**. Since, Every subset $H$ of $\{x_n\}$ consists entirely of isolated points in $X$, they possess no accumulation point in $X$. Therefore, no element from $H^c$ can be at $0$ distance from $H$ and hence, cannot be a part of the boundary. Thus, the boundary is included in $H$ itself and is hence closed in $X$.

$4.$ **False.** The limit point of $\{y_{m_n}\}$ **may not** belong to $\{y_{m_n}\}$. Therefore, it may not be closed.

$5.$ **False.** The set $\{y_n\} - \{y_{m_n}\}$ consists entirely of isolated points of $y_n$ since $y_n$ has only one convergent sub-sequence. From point $3$, these set of isolated points are closed in $X$.

Am I correct in my attempt? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't see any flaws. In 1., when you say $S=\mathbb N$, you should also specify $X$.

Comment: @amsmath thank you

Comment: @amsmath Would it be right to say that every subset $H$ consists entirely of points which are isolated in $X$?

Comment: What do you mean by "isolated in $X$"?

Comment: $dist(h, X-\{h\})>0~\forall~h \in H$

Comment: Is it not the case that $(y_n)$ must be constant? Since any subsequence of $(y_{m_n})$ (with any finite collection of excised $(y_n)$ terms added back in) must also be convergent, does it not follow?

Comment: @MathMan Then definitely not. Consider $H = \mathbb N$ in $X = \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Bungo if $y_{m_n}$ is the constant sequence, then, it's possible

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced by your answer to 4 or 5. Here's why:

**Claim**: $(y_n)_n$ is constant.

**Proof**: If $\# \{y_{m_n}\}_n \geq 2$, then we can create a different convergent subsequence of $(y_n)$ by simply taking out all the terms $(y_{m_n})_n$ which have a particular value, provided that there are infinitely many terms left over. (Such a value is guaranteed by the infinite pigeonhole principle).

Likewise, if there is a value $a = y_N \in \{y_{n}\}\backslash \{y_{m_n}\}$, then adding on this $N$th term to $(y_{m_n})$ yields another distinct convergent sequence! $\qquad\square$

From this, it's clear that

4) $\{y_{m_n}\}=\{\ast\}=\{y_{n}\}$ is open in $\{y_{n}\}$, and

5) $\{y_{n}\}\backslash \{y_{m_n}\}=\emptyset$ is open in $X$.

$ $

Otherwise, I have no problems!